# How to add CheckboxListTile to the SlidingUpPanel

Tags: flutter, dart, checkboxlist, listtile

I'm trying to add the `CheckboxListTile` on `SlidingUpPanel` but it shows error as
" `The element type 'List<CheckboxListTile>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.` "

how can I fix this and make the code usable?

here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sliding_up_panel/sliding_up_panel.dart';

final Color color = Color(0xff181725);

class Filters extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Filters> createState() => _FiltersState();
}

class _FiltersState extends State<Filters> {
  bool isChecked = false;

  Map<String, bool> categories = <String, bool>{
    "Eggs": false,
    "Noodles & Pasta": false,
    "Chips & Crisps": false,
    "Fast Food": false,
  };
  Map<String, bool> brand = <String, bool>{
    "Individual Callection": false,
    "Cocola": false,
    "Ifad": false,
    "Kazi Farmas": false,
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    BorderRadiusGeometry radius = BorderRadius.only(
      topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
      topRight: Radius.circular(30),
    );
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: Icon(
          Icons.close_rounded,
          color: color,
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          "Filters",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: color,
            fontFamily: "Gilroy",
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 20,
            wordSpacing: 1,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: SlidingUpPanel(
        boxShadow: const [
          BoxShadow(
            blurRadius: 0,
            color: Colors.transparent,
          ),
        ],
        borderRadius: radius,
        panel: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(
                '''Categories''',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: color,
                  fontSize: 24,
                  fontFamily: "Gilroy",
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                ),
              ),
              ListView(
                children: [
                  categories.keys.map((String key) {
                    return CheckboxListTile(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      ),
                      controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                      activeColor: Color(0xff53B175),
                      checkColor: Color(0xffFFFFFF),
                      value: categories[key],
                      onChanged: (bool? value) {
                        setState(() {
                          categories[key] = value!;
                        });
                      },
                      title: Text(
                        "{$key}",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                          fontFamily: "Gilroy",
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        collapsed: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color(0xffF2F3F2),
            borderRadius: radius,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: clear `.toList(),` in your `return CheckboxListTile`

Comment: remove your [  and ]